# How to get the project root of django project

Tags: python, django

I am using django 3

I want to get root directory of project.

I googled around and found that I should use this

`SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` in settings.py though,

I can't figure out how to use `SITE_ROOT` in other script.

Maybe this is quite silly and newbee question though,, 
ーーーーーーーーーーーーーー

thanks to @neverwalkaloner

It works.

```
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.SITE_ROOT)
```

but it does not work on apache with wsgi.py. show `/` only.

`wsgi.py`

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.myconf.local')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

`manage.py`

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.myconf.local')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `from projectname.settings import SITE_ROOT`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access django settings using [`django.conf`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code) module. In any django file you can do something like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.SITE_ROOT)
```

From django docs:

> Also note that your code should not import from either global_settings
>   or your own settings file. django.conf.settings abstracts the concepts
>   of default settings and site-specific settings; it presents a single
>   interface. It also decouples the code that uses settings from the
>   location of your settings.

Comment: Thank you very much , it is quite simple and good explanation. By the way ,it works on `python manage.py runserver` but not apache with `wsgi.py`. I am struggling with...

Comment: @whitebear probably you are using different setting file for production?

Comment: No, I have apache server in local. so I use completely same setting.

Comment: It also works on remote server, maybe the problem is from the local server I use(e sometimes work and sometimes not. much unstable,,,,because of cache??,but it looks another problem.). So I marked it as answer. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should import your settings module and use SITE_ROOT as below wherever you need it in your app as below :

```
from django.conf import settings
...
settings.SITE_ROOT
```

Comment: Thank you @Théophile Godard  , another answer gave me the details so made that final answer though, your answer was also the good help.